Problems with changing the status from pending to rejected/approved
I do not know much about js, but I tried to submit the data by clicking on the button.
The project is about approve or reject orders in the panel of the owner of the shop.
Things in Django admin went well, and I can change it through the admin interface, but I also want it to be user-friendly so the owner of the shop can approve the request by clicking on approve and reject it by clicking on the cancel button.
In conclusion, I want to make a logic that whenever the owner clicks on the approve button, the pending in the database changes to approved, and the same for the reject.
When I click on the button(reject or approval) it gives me 405 error.
My views.py:
def update_appointment_status(request: HttpRequest):
 timeslice_id = request.GET.get('timeslice_id')        status = request.GET.get('status')        timeslice = get_object_or_404(TimeSlice, id=timeslice_id)
  if status == 'approve':       timeslice.approve()   
  elif status == 'refuse':            timeslice.refuse()
return JsonResponse({'success': True})

My js codes:
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Approve button click handler
    $('.approve-btn').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var timesliceId = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/approve/',  // Adjust the URL to your specific endpoint
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'timeslice_id': timesliceId,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
            },
            success: function(response) {
                alert('Appointment approved.');
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert('Error: ' + error);
            }
        });
    });

    // Refuse button click handler
    $('.refuse-btn').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var timesliceId = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/refuse/',  // Adjust the URL to your specific endpoint
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'timeslice_id': timesliceId,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
            },
            success: function(response) {
                alert('Appointment refused.');
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert('Error: ' + error);
            }
        });
    });
});

My templates:
 {% for slice in time_slices %}
    {% if slice.business_line == barber %}
        <li>
            {{ slice.start_time }} - {{ slice.end_time }}
            <p>State: {{ slice.get_appointment_state_display }}</p>
            <form method="post" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="timeslice_id" value="{{ slice.id }}">
                <button type="submit" name="approve" class="approve-btn">Approve</button>
                <button type="submit" name="refuse" class="refuse-btn">Refuse</button>
            </form>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

I am also sending the data with a hidden integerfield form.

Why are you accessing the GET attribute of the HttpRequest when you are sending POST requests? When you do that, Django will throw a HttpResponseNotAllowed.

You are making a "POST"' request through AJAX, but your python function looks for "GET"' request.
Updated python function:-
def update_appointment_status(request: HttpRequest):
  if request.method == "POST":
      timeslice_id = request.data.get('timeslice_id')        
      status = request.data.get('status') 
      timeslice = get_object_or_404(TimeSlice, id=timeslice_id)
      if status == 'approve':       
           timeslice.approve()   
      elif status == 'refuse':            
           timeslice.refuse()
      else:
           return JsonResponse({"message": "Invalid status"}, status=400)

      return JsonResponse({'success': True}, status=200)
   return JsonResponse({'message': 'Invalid request'}, status=405)


Django template:-
    {% if slice.business_line == barber %}
        <li>
            {{ slice.start_time }} - {{ slice.end_time }}
            <p>State: {{ slice.get_appointment_state_display }}</p>
                <button type="submit" name="approve" data-id="{{ slice.id }}" class="approve-btn">Approve</button>
                <button type="submit" name="refuse" data-id="{{ slice.id }}" class="refuse-btn">Refuse</button>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

Use this instead for CSRF
jQuery:-
'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{ csrf_token }}";

